# Typescript ensure generic object does not contain property

Tags: typescript

I have a generic function which takes in an object, however the object cannot contain properties with the format `__property__`. Currently I do:

```js
type RemoveProps = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends `__${infer _K}__` ? never : K]: T[K];
}

function doSomething<T extends {}>(arg: RemoveProps<T>): 
{
    // ...
}
```

This is fine, but it still allows you to do:

```js
doSomething<{ __not_allowed__: any }>(arg);
```

Is there a way to get typescript to throw an error if the generic type contains these properties?

Comment: This might be a problem better solved with an ESLint rule that allows you to ban certain named properties based on a regex pattern.  A quick search and I found [this project](https://github.com/remithomas/eslint-plugin-ban) which might do it, but I haven't looked into it very thoroughly

Comment: @ChrisBarr That would be fine if the rule wasn't applied project wide, but its only to the function. Besides the reason for excluding them is because the internals utilize variables of that format that the user shouldn't use.

Comment: @jcalz Ah yeah that approach works perfectly haha, I forgot you can just map it to never instead of doing a conditional map on the key, thanks! Feel free to write up a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to map bad property value types to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) instead of omitting them entirely.  Omitting a property doesn't prevent assignability: `{ __x__: 0, y: 1 }` extends `{ y: 1}` but it does not extend `{ __x__: never, y: 1 }`:

```
type ProhibitProps<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends `__${string}__` ? never : T[K]
}

function doSomething<T extends ProhibitProps<T>>(
  arg: T
) { }


doSomething<{ __not_allowed__: any }>({ ok: 123 }); // error!
// -------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '{ __not_allowed__: any; }' does not satisfy the 
//   constraint 'ProhibitProps<{ __not_allowed__: any; }>'.
// Types of property '__not_allowed__' are incompatible.
// Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.

doSomething<{ ok: 123 }>({ ok: 123 }); // okay
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewBYEsBGLjwWAzgHgBUA+KAXigG8AoKKAbQGkoUA7KAawhAQDMpCAXQBcUZhAAewCKwAmuKAAMA+soAklXMDhsA5gF9ViqAH4orCADcIcKKMJNB1fdWq8ArqwDGwFAnayCADKCAC2EMCorLpEUJLScgrYqBhYiHhExMQAFLRQAIZwuvbUAJRUUC6ugSHhkXr4lFCqrAjAyvkANp0IAO4Qsqqi+awglTlNCByiAIwATADMlaUA3FAA9OtxcIhwAITUm1AAtKdnx6QAftc3t3f3N4dbhODQAORNLW0d3X0DQwVRmt9G8oIEIApWsAoLh8r5cLwxpFoE86FAvP4tHB8mxoW9kuhMNgMp9lFCfj1+oNlMMgeM3gA6VEvSAKPhQMDpGygKBvL7tLqU-7KUGFaBsDGhMBw9CdCBMo4s94jECglCQtoFXC4FC6Vj5NByqDABDG168izWOCM6rBMIRKIxSbTKDzJb6CZQKazRbLNZHKb5ECuIA)